# Python3 - Multiple inputs

Tags: python-3.x, input

I need to take in input like the following:

```
Enter two floating point values: 54.99, 32.3
```

In one line, I want to take in both values and save them as a floating point number but I have been unable to. So far I have the following:

```
val1, val2 = input("Enter two floating point values: ").split(",")
```

In that same line, I want to cast them to floating point numbers. How can that be done?

I do not want to do this:

```
val1, val2 = input("Enter two floating point values: ").split(",")
val1 = float(val1)
val2 = float(val2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether if there is a better way, but you can do it with list comprehension in one line:

```
val1, val2 = [float(item) for item in input("Enter two floating point values: ").split(",")]
```

Another option that you can do is by using the map function:

```
val1, val2 = map(float(input("Enter two floating point values: ").split(","))
```

Note that in Python 3.x the second version returns a map object rather than a list.

Although, you can convert it to list by doing:

```
val1, val2 = list(map(float,input("Enter two floating point values: ").split(",")))
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Hatefiend , Your'e welcome, I've added another option that you can do at the answer.

Comment: you don't need lambda in the map, you can just do: 
`val1, val2 = map(float, raw_input("whatever").split(",")`

Comment: This question is tagged with `python-3.x` and you are using `raw_input`.

Comment: @TheClonerx , Thanks for noticing, fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this:

```py
# taking two inputs at a time 
# Python program showing how to 
# multiple input using split

x, y = input("Enter a two value: ").split() 
print("Number of boys: ", x) 
print("Number of girls: ", y) 
print()

# hit enter and give two numbers(Floating or Int- keep a space in between numbers)

Enter a two value: 12.25 58.45
Number of boys:  12.25
Number of girls:  58.45
```